# How do I set the height of a div to the be some % of the height of the current viewport?

Tags: css

I tried `height: 100%` but that seems to just be the height of the viewport.

My page scrolls, so I would like for the height to be set to the entire window basically.

Here is a live example - http://jsfiddle.net/gtKBs/750/ (trying to figure out the `divider` height).

Note, I don't want to move the div, I just want to set the height to the maximum height of the window.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Or even better yet, what I would like to happen is as I scroll the `divider` stays the same proportion and scrolls with me - i.e. say it is total height of `90%`, then as I scroll, I always see the space @ top & bottom, indicating that it is just `90%` height of the current viewport.

**Edit 2**

This is what I am trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/ryBZG/1/  A span 2 divs, `span2`, `span9` where the `span2` is a sidebar and the `span9` is the content of the page. I want to put a divider between them.

Comment: Your issue is related to the `position` on the `#blue_box`, where it is not in flow with `body` and `body` does not take it's dimensionality. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gtKBs/753/

Comment: So is there anyway to get it working without moving the `div class="divider">` inside the `div id=blue box`? Also...see updated question of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What is it you're trying to make? The way you have it setup, I'm not sure you can.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/ryBZG/1/  A span 2 divs, `span2`, `span9` where the `span2` is a sidebar and the `span9` is the content of the page. I want to put a divider between them.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ryBZG/2/ You shouldn't use an element wedge to create a divider; there's almost always some between way.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I am using Twitter Bootstrap's classes. What does `display: table` do? Is that necessary? I feel like it may break the layout of my site - because it interferes with the responsive rules of the `container` class.

Comment: I figured you were using some kind of grid, with `span2` and `span9`. `display: table` is just a shorthand way of making elements expand into their containers like a table would. It's not supported in IE7. You should be doing your layout *with* Bootstrap. Do you have the HTML5 Boilerplate or something?

Comment: I am doing my layout with Bootstrap. Not using an HTML5 Boilerplate. Just writing plain old vanilla HTML using Bootstrap's classes in a Rails App.

Comment: the `display:table` seems to come with a border. Is that normal? Scratch that...it seems to be some styles from Bootstrap on the class `content`. If you add this as the answer, I will accept it!

Comment: That thick gray border I put in the middle to simulate what you were after, which is a saner way than trying to hover a `div` in a `position` soup. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Nah...I was seeing something else.

Comment: Actually one last thing...this is just a fixed border from top to bottom...what happens if I want it to just hover (i.e. about 5% from bottom and 5% from top).

Comment: You should be using Bootstrap's grid to do your layout.

Comment: I am....which is why this is giving me such a warm time. I am using `row-fluid`, and the respective spans. All I want is a floating vertical divider between my `span2` and `span9` divs. Both of which fit within my `row-fluid` responsive div. Also...the `border-right` for this sidebar div stops at the end of the length of that div.

Comment: You would need to fake the border top/bottom margin: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ryBZG/3/

Comment: The vertical line in that goes flush to the bottom of the page.

Comment: See how you're doing all those float left/right and clear fix stuff, that's what `display: table` and `display: inline-block` solve. Anyhow, you mean the fiddle I just commented? In Firefox, there's a gap at the top and bottom (which is a margin on the container div).

Comment: Hrmm....yah...that last one you just did /3/ in Chrome it is flush at the bottom of the page :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27001/discussion-between-marcamillion-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the CSS of your divider div to the following

```
.divider{
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    border-left:1px solid white;
}
```

As your `#bluebox` has a fixed `width: 550px;` I recommend to set your `.divider`'s width to a fixed width (`260px`), too.

HTH
Andy